# Renegotiation Indication Extension for TLS v1.2

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I can have 3 cases:

- 1: the client supports only v1_2
- 2: only v1_3
- 3: both v1_2 and v1_3.

For this cases I will set:

1. SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_2_VERSION);  SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_2_VERSION)
2. SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_3_VERSION);  SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_3_VERSION)
3. SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_2_VERSION);  SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_3_VERSION)

In each case I set the ciphers:

```
const char* cipher_list = "C1:C2";
const char* cipher_suites = "C3:C4";

SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, cipher_list);  // v1_2
SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites(cctx, cipher_suites);  // v1_3
```

```
Case1: Cipher Suites (3 suites)
                Cipher Suite: C1 (0x130)
                Cipher Suite: C2 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)

Case2: Cipher Suites (3 suites)
                Cipher Suite: C3 (0x131)
                Cipher Suite: C4 (0xc02g)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)

Case3: Cipher Suites (5 suites)
                Cipher Suite: C1 (0x130)
                Cipher Suite: C2 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: C3 (0x131)
                Cipher Suite: C4 (0xc02g)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
```

As I understand by default Renegotiation Indication Extension is empty.

I need to send TLS renegotiation indidication extension for TLS v1.2 since only TLS v1.2 will need to support secure key renegotiation, how could I do that and how can that work in case 3?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: A client supporting TLS1.2 (or lower) and rfc5746 (which pretty much everything does since about 2012) doing an _initial_ handshake must send _either_ the ERI SCSV _or_ an RI extension with empty contents; OpenSSL chooses the former. If you didn't send either, the 'default' would be nonsupport of 5746, which most servers today reject. Only when actually renegotiating (subsequent handshake on existing connection) does the RI extension contain data, which OpenSSL supplies automatically; your code does not do anything.

Comment: Setting ALLOW_UNSAFE in OpenSSL client only means the client will allow connection to a server that does not accept 5746 (which as I said practically all do); OpenSSL always offers 5746 (and supports it if accepted) (as you saw, it offers even on a 1.3-only ClientHello where any resulting connection can't use it). Similarly for an OpenSSL server it allows connections from a client that does not offer 5746; that's also rare, but maybe slightly less rare. PS: I didn't notice before your code examples have 'set_min' twice; I assume you meant, and actually have, 'set_min' plus 'set_max'.

Answer (score -1):

Answer depends upon which version of openssl library you are using.